# abcpdf content front of header and footer

Tags: c#, header, footer, abcpdf

I am trying to create an structure using abcpdf that suppose to be like this:

header
content
footer

**P.S: content needs to be "front of" header and footer**

In other words, I need to have my content starting from **y = 0 to y = 100%**; My header starting from **y = 0 to y = 200**; My footer starting from **y = 700 to y = 100%**. **(Values here are just samples)**

I hope I am being clear.

At the moment I have those methods:

```
private void CreateDocHeader(Doc theDoc, int theCount, string content)
    {
        theDoc.Rect.String = "0 660 600 825";
        theDoc.MediaBox.String = theDoc.Rect.String;
        for (int i = 1; i <= theCount; i++)
        {
            theDoc.PageNumber = i;
            theDoc.AddImageHtml(content);
        }
    }

    private void CreateDocFooter(Doc theDoc, int theCount, string content)
    {
        theDoc.Rect.String = "0 200 600 10";
        theDoc.MediaBox.String = theDoc.Rect.String;
        for (int i = 1; i <= theCount; i++)
        {
            theDoc.PageNumber = i;
            theDoc.AddImageHtml(content);
        }
    }

    private void CreateDocContent(Doc theDoc, int theID, string theContent, ref int theCount)
    {
        theDoc.Rect.String = "0 800 600 10";
        theDoc.MediaBox.String = theDoc.Rect.String;
        theID = theDoc.AddImageHtml(theContent);
        while (theDoc.Chainable(theID))
        {
            theDoc.Page = theDoc.AddPage();
            theID = theDoc.AddImageToChain(theID);
        }
        theCount = theDoc.PageCount;
    }
```

Anyone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Hpos and Vpos properties to do that :-

For header, do this:

```
theDoc.HPos = 0.5;
theDoc.VPos = 1.0;
```

this will keep your header in left alignment.

For footer, do this:

```
theDoc.HPos = 1.0;
theDoc.VPos = 0.5;
```

this will keep your footer in right alignment.

Hope this helps.

**Addition:**

For having the Z position, that is have the different tiers for the header/footer and content, use the **Layer** property. This property alongwith the **LayerCount** property, you can have the solution.

For more reference go through this documentation:-

http://www.websupergoo.com/helppdfnet/source/5-abcpdf/doc/2-properties/layer.htm
http://www.websupergoo.com/helppdfnet/source/5-abcpdf/doc/2-properties/layercount.htm

Comment: I got it, but do you know how can I set the "Z" position? To make header as tier 0, footer as tier 0 and content as tier 1? Thanks for your reply!